# Should a wcf client proxy be Singleton or Transient in .net core API app

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

We are consuming wcf services in a high volume API. (up to 10.000rpm)

In the startup.cs file I have registered the services as a Singleton, but not sure if they should be Transient.

The wcf proxy classes were generated by the svcutil.

The recommended way for httpclient is to use Singleton, but does that same apply for wcf clients?

All endpoints are stateless.

Comment: I would suggest testing/benchmarking it first. If the cost of initializing the proxies is expensive then you do not want to be creating a new instance every time it is needed. So I guess it boils down to *it depends*.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting question.
You should use a singleton I think.
This article from the asp.net monsters could be helpful: 
https://aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/ 
With best regards